# how to applicate interceptor in a controller on a project MVC WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, aop, interceptor, spring.net

I try to use an interceptor in my project

I received a error classic in spring.net when I try to call a method of controller

**stack trace :**

```
  An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to cast object of type 'CompositionAopProxy_f2b2933019534ca9be66f06255ab2271' to type 'xxx.API.Controllers.UserController'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidCastException","StackTrace":"   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
 at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

There is the description of differents files

**Controller.cs :**

```
[RoutePrefix("rest/users")]
public class UserController : BaseController,IUserController
{
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(UserController));
private UserLogic userLogic { get; set; }


    public UserController() 
    {
       // userLogic = (UserLogicBase)xxx.ExceptionHandlingAspect.ExceptionHandlingAspect.GetProxy(new UserLogicImpl(), "GetAll|Get|Save|Update|Delete");
    }

     // GET: /api/users
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("",Name = "UserRoute")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
    {
      //  var start = DateTime.Now;
        Criterias criterias = InitContextFilter();
     //   var end = DateTime.Now;

      //  var res = end - start; 

        try
        {

            ICollection<User> users = userLogic.GetAll(criterias);
            ICollection<UserDTO> dtos = DTOFactory.convertUserDTOList(users);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("total-count", criterias.Count.ToString());
            return Ok(dtos);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, this);
        }

    }


    // GET: /api/users/{Id}
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("{Id}")]          
    public IHttpActionResult Get(long Id)
    {           
        log.Debug("Get User");  

        User user = userLogic.Get(Id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        UserDTO dto = DTOFactory.createDTO(user,false);

        return Ok(dto);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody] UserDTO dto)
    {
        try
        {
            User user = Mapper.Map<User>(dto);
            user = userLogic.Save(user);


            dto = DTOFactory.createDTO(user, false);
           return Created(Url.Route("UserRoute", null), dto);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, this);
        }

    }

    [HttpPut]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("{Id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Update(long Id, [FromBody] UserDTO dto)
    {
        try
        {
            User update = userLogic.Get(Id);
            if (update != null || Id != dto.id.Value)
            {
                DTOFactory.applyPropertiesTo(dto, update);
               update = userLogic.Update(update);

                dto = DTOFactory.createDTO(update);
                return Ok(dto);
            }
            else
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, this);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, this);
        }

    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("{Id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(long Id)
    {

        try
        {
            User update = userLogic.Get(Id);
            if (update != null)
            {
                var user = userLogic.Delete(Id);

                UserDTO dto = DTOFactory.createDTO(user);
                return Ok(dto);
            }
            else
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, this);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, this);
        }
    }

}
```

**Interface :**

```
interface IUserController
{

    IHttpActionResult GetAll();
    IHttpActionResult Get(long Id);
    IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody] UserDTO dto);
    IHttpActionResult Update(long Id, [FromBody] UserDTO dto);
    IHttpActionResult Delete(long Id);

}
```

**config xml :**

```js
  <object id="debugInterceptor" type="xxx.API.Interceptors.DebugInterceptor, xxx.API"/>

  <object id="UserController" singleton="false" type="xxx.API.Controllers.UserController, xxx.API">
    <property name="userLogic">
      <ref object="UserLogicImpl" />
    </property>
  </object>

 <object id="ProxyCreator" type="Spring.Aop.Framework.AutoProxy.ObjectNameAutoProxyCreator, Spring.Aop">
    <property name="ObjectNames">
      <list>
        <value>*Controller</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="InterceptorNames">
      <list>
        <value>debugInterceptor</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>
```

**Startup.cs**

```
  public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.DependencyResolver = new SpringDependencyResolver(ContextRegistry.GetContext());
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);  // TODO: change option to only allow the web application domain
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
}

public class SpringDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IApplicationContext _appContext;

    public SpringDependencyResolver(IApplicationContext appContext)
    {
        _appContext = appContext;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _appContext.Dispose();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> objects = _appContext.GetObjectsOfType(serviceType);
        return objects.Values.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> objects = _appContext.GetObjectsOfType(serviceType);
        return objects.Values;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new SpringDependencyResolver(_appContext);
    }
}
```

**Interceptor :**

```
 public class DebugInterceptor : IMethodInterceptor
{
    public object Invoke(IMethodInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before: " + invocation.Method.ToString());
        object rval = invocation.Proceed();
        Console.WriteLine("After:  " + invocation.Method.ToString());
        return rval;
    }

}
```

It's is possible anybody to explain the true problem and help me to find a solution to add an interceptor on the controller web Api

Answer (score 0):

You need to create inheritance based proxies, **WebAPI** will try to cast to a controller, using the default value your created proxies will not derive from your class.

Just add to your proxy creator:

```
<property name="ProxyTargetType" value="true" />
```

Like this:

```
<object id="ProxyCreator" type="Spring.Aop.Framework.AutoProxy.ObjectNameAutoProxyCreator, Spring.Aop">
<property name="ObjectNames">
  <list>
    <value>*Controller</value>
  </list>
</property>
<property name="ProxyTargetType" value="true" />
<property name="InterceptorNames">
  <list>
    <value>debugInterceptor</value>
  </list>
</property>
</object>
```

When `ProxyTargetType` is set to `true` you need to be **sure** your methods are `virtual` otherwise **will not be intercepted**.